# How to solve 2 tetrated 0.5 times?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, tetration

I've been really interested in tetration lately. So I came up with a seemingly simple problem to solve, which is 2 tetrated 0.5 times, which I'll write as the following.

2^^0.5

To make sense of this notation, consider the following where A represents a real number:

A^A = A^^2

A^A^A = A^^3

etc.

Here's where my problem is. The answer I got and the one on Wikipedia are different. I'm assuming the answer on Wikipedia is the correct one, but I would like to know what I did wrong.

So here's how I tried to solve this problem:

First I say 2^^0.5 is the same as the "super square root" of 2 (I don't exactly know how to format this), which is equal to X.

Next I tetrate or "super square" both sides by 2, so the "super square root" of 2 becomes 2, and X becomes X tetrated 2 times, which looks like the following:

X^^2 = 2

Then I rewrite X tetrated 2 times as X to the power of X.

X^X = 2

Finally I graphed Y = X^X and Y = 2 on my calculator and found the intersection point in the first quadrant, which should be the answer of 2^^0.5. And I got the following:

X = 1.559610469 (approximately)

However, the answer to 2^^0.5 on Wikpedia is approximately 1.45933.

Does anyone know what I did wrong when trying to solve this problem? Any answers would be appreciated. Also, if you have any questions of what I did or what I'm asking, feel free to ask.

Comment: "Tetration" is not a quite current word. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) for a definition.

Comment: By graphing $x^x$ and $2$ and looking for the intersection, what you're solving for is actually x^^2 = 2, or super square root of x = 2, which doesn't seem to be what you want. If you reexamine the section of the Wikipedia article you're quoting from, you can find a method for approximating non-integer tower heights.

Comment: The "quadratic" approximation is used to get 1.45933. The article says that the quadratic approximation does **not** hold the property that it "cancels out". However solving in the manner you did does hold the "cancel out" property. In other words, your method has  $(2\text{^^}0.5)\text{^^}2 = 2$.
That is $1.559610469^{1.559610469} \approx 2$. So you're not using the same approximation method as Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

The disparity is because you're starting from a different interpretation of the expression "2^^0.5" than Wikipedia is. You're saying that (essentially) it ought to be the case that for any $y$, ($y$^^0.5)^^2$=y$. This is a natural extension of the related law of exponentiation - but why would laws of exponentiation apply to tetration? Notice that it doesn't work for other numbers in place of $0.5$ and $2$:

$$(x\text{^^}2)\text{^^}2 = (x^x)\text{^^}2 = (x^x)^{x^x} = x^{x\cdot x^x} \neq x^{x^{x^x}} = x\text{^^}4$$

I can't think of a good, natural way to define $x$^^$0.5$, and the Wikipedia article on [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Real_heights) agrees. It's not an easy task to extend things that are naturally defined only on integers into the reals - we should really do a better job of expressing to students how *weird* it is that it worked out just fine for multiplication and exponentiation.